# Joint account with my home equity

Tags: checking-account

Can second person on my joint account write checks to deposit to their own credit union if proceeds were from my home equity?

Comment: Probably.  Wouldn't this depend on what limitations the account had?  Often this kind of question is best asked of your lender.  Does your home equity line of credit allow the writing of checks?

Comment: It was the cash out of the sell of my home. I was to invest the amount for future needs. This person wrote himself checks out of the account and deposited in his own bank account without following through with our agreement.

Comment: @Pat: The bank probably does not know or care where the money in the account came from.   I would suggest getting in touch with the police and/or a lawyer.

Comment: If you put the money into the joint account, the bank will apply the rules for that account (that is, whoever has permission to control funds in the joint account can control all the funds in the joint account, no matter where they came from).  Some joint accounts require multiple accountholders to approve a transfer, but on most each individual accountholder can transact using the funds.

Answer (score 1):

When you set up a joint account you tell the bank what rules to apply for how money can be withdrawn. Typically you say either that any person can withdraw funds on their own, or all  owners must sign. If it is the former then a person can take out money on their own.

Unless you have an agreement otherwise, putting money in a joint account (especially one anyone can withdraw from) is implicitly stating that the money belongs to both of you.   If you can show that it was understood the money was intended to be yours alone you might have a case.